# How to create front-end form that is unrelated to contact form

Tags: admin, cms, forms

I am interested in creating a submission form that allows users to submit ideas related to new products. It has nothing to do with the sales or order functionality of Magento. I just need it to be a simple form on a CMS page that is logged into the database and made viewable in the admin section. I have come across several tutorials that allow you to extend a basic contact form but that will not work in this instance. Any general guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: You can just duplicate the contact module, replace the inputs with what you need, and instead of sending e-mails like the contact form does, just save the values in the database. Create for that a simple CRUD module and on frontend add the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must write code. You must write a module for this to work clean. I have write a similar module where i displayed a survey and based on user selection i was showing products they want.

If you are willing to create such a module you could use this [generator](http://www.silksoftware.com/magento-module-creator/#.UyM1tImSy68).

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a simple custom module, but it may be easier to find an existing extension.  There are quite a few out there for contact forms, surveys, etc. For example:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/rebimol/extension/7232/webforms

Answer (score 1):

I completely agree with the answers given, that to create this custom form you'll need to write some code. That said, it doesn't sound like you necessarily **need** to use Magento's forms, if you really are just collecting ideas on new products. As relatively easy as this would be to create a module, have you considered using a third party survey related tool for this?

I know that [Google Drive](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/87809?hl=en) allows you to create forms and embedded them on your website. Unless you have some sort of tight integration with this form and your product catalog within Magento, you could simply create a form using Google (or whatever other platform you choose) and embed the form into a CMS page.

If you do prefer to go with a strictly Magento solution, if you are not comfortable with Magento development I'd recommend finding a free third party module that does *almost* what you want, then spend a bit of time modifying the module to fit your needs.